# with Intel DP55WB mother board, which graphic card with cuda support is compatible?

Tags: graphics-cards, motherboard

I have a PC which has the following specifications:

**MotherBoard**: Intel DP55WB
**Processor**: Intel Core i5 7500
**Graphics** card: Nvidia 9600 GT

I don't want to change any other component.

I recently came to know that my graphic card doesn't support CUDA.

I require a graphic card, which best fits my hardware so that I can run complex applications / algo on my PC.

Comment: What exacly do you want to use it for?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to change out the GPU. I would reccommend using a GTX 10xx or RTX 20xx Super graphics card. Which one you need exacly depends on your exact use case.

Answer (score 1):

Your CPU is an i5 750 not 7500 according to your motherboard's specs.
You can basically install any GPU in it but you will be limited by the rest of your system which is 10 years + old.

I'll advice a 1050 Ti or RTX 3050 range GPU.

Unlike what was suggested above, be careful not to go for older/current gen high end gpu such as RTX Super series, your power supply wont be able to provide enough juice to it.